# python removing special char from dict

Tags: python

Im using python3 and im converting string of output to list.
the list ends up having special chars id like to remove and havent found a way to do

this is the script:

```
bashCommand = "some bash command"
stdoutdata = subprocess.getoutput(bashCommand)
lines = stdoutdata.splitlines()
result = {"data": []}

for line in lines:
    line = line.rstrip()
    entry = line.split(":")
    result["data"].append({"{#NAME}":entry[0],"{#STATUS}": entry[1]})
print(json.dumps(result))
```

the output from bash command is this:

```
GENERAL-1 : UP
GENERAL-2 : UP
GENERAL-3 : UP
```

this is the result:

```
{"data": [{"{#NAME}": "GENERAL-1", "{#STATUS}": " UP\u001b[0m"}, {"{#NAME}": "GENERAL-2", "{#STATUS}": " UP\u001b[0m"}, {"{#NAME}": "GENERAL-3", "{#STATUS}": " UP\u001b[0m"}]}
```

Id like to remove the \u001b[0m from the dict.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just parse the `entry[1]` and replace the `\u001b[0m` to empty string, modifying this line to:

```
result["data"].append({"{#NAME}":entry[0],"{#STATUS}": entry[1].replace('\u001b[0m', ''})
```

Comment: Thanks you! added it on this line `line = line.rstrip().replace('\u001b[0m','')`